# Generate html and render in qweb

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

Is it possible generate html in .py file and render in qweb?

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="paperformat_time" model="report.paperformat">
            <field name="name">Time</field>
            <field name="font_size">10</field>
        </record>

        <report id="time_qweb" model="hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet" string="Time" 
        report_type="qweb-pdf" name="time.report_time" file="time.report_time" />

        <record id="time_qweb" model="ir.actions.report.xml">
            <field name="paperformat_id" ref="time.paperformat_time" />
        </record>
      </data>
</openerp>

qweb    

<template id="report_time">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="t">
            <span t-esc="t.__compute_html()" />
            <div class="page">
                <span t-field="t.html_text " />
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

.py file

```
class Time(models.Model):

   _inherit = 'hr_timesheet_sheet.sheet'

   html_text = fields.Html(string = 'Html')

   @api.one
   def _compute_html(self):
        html_value = "<h1>TEST</h1>" 
        html_value += "<h1>TEST 2</h1>"

        self.html_text = html_value
```

eg.

```
html_value = "<h1> + employee_id.name + "</h1>" 
html_value += "<h1> + employee_id.phone + "</h1>"
```

now I need html_value  render in qweb in put in `<div class="page"> put here html_value </div>`

Now I save text in database, any better solution?................................

Comment: If you really want to "render" html_value in .py file, then just add it to a cotnroller
request.aprams['html_value'] = html_value

then in template <span t-esc="html_value"/>

Comment: @TadeuszKarpinski  Any simple example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50750410/generate-html-and-render-in-qweb

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can if you have a variable that have html code if you use `t-esc` or `t-field` odoo will print it as text.

If you want to render it use.  `t-raw`

```
  <div t-raw="doc.some_attribute" > </div>
```

Or

```
   <t t-raw="doc.some_attribute" > </t>
```

Comment: Tnx for help any, Do you have any more detailed example. GL

Comment: Xhat you mean by example. You could put your code in the question. How are computing the value.

Comment: I'm add my example above, all work fine but now I save html text in database and that text display in qweb. Any better solution without save text in db.

Comment: Yes there is first i think i deserve to accept my answer. And instead of saving the result in the field just return it directly in the funcion `retun value_html`  and use api.multi because api.one the returned result will be a list. Then you can directly call the function in your template `<t t-raw="doc.compute_html()"  />` remember use api.multi. it's easer

Comment: And make your method public by removing the '_' because i think odoo will prevent you from calling it.if not just keep it like that

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<span t-raw="my_html_field"/>
```

Here my_html_field is your html formated data

Answer (score 0):

Since Odoo version 15, t-raw is deprecated. You need to render the HTML in a safe way using Python, then parse that into XML. [Reference](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/01875541b1a8131cb)

```py
import markupsafe
...

class YourController(http.Controller):
    ...
    @http.route(...)
    def your_rendering_method(self):
        ...
        return request.render("YOUR_TEMPLATE", {"YOUR_FIELD": markupsafe.Markup("<a href='https://www.stackoverflow.com'>Stack Overflow</a>")})
```

```
<t t-esc="YOUR_FIELD" />
```